# Behavior of HttpsURLConnectioin with default implementation of HostnameVerifier and SSLSocketFactory

Tags: java, ssl, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to understand a piece of code that does not override HostnameVerifier and SSLSocketFactory for HttpsURLConnection. The current code is able to make the SSL request fine, which is a little confusing to me. 
How does the default implementation of HostnameVerifier and SSLSocketFactory classes work? Does it verify the certificate CA and hostname or it bypasses all these checks all together?

Also, is there any special behavior if the request has localhost in it? 
The URL looks like this
https://localhost:/

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will check the CA certificate against the trusted ca-certificates in the trusted store of the JDK `jre/lib/security/cacerts` or whatever you have configured.

It will also check, that all certificates in the chain are trusted, not only the immediate signer. It will, by default, not check online for revoked certificates, but you can enable that in the `java.security` policy file.

It will also check the hostname against the certificate.
It supports additional CNs and wildcard CNs.

Extended question regarding localhost:

`localhost` is just a hostname like any other. It must be listed in the certificate. But you will not find an official CA to give you that certificate, I guess :-)

If you want to play with your real cert on localhost, you address it with a different hostname. If you want to run through a cert for `foo.bar.com`, add to your `hosts` file (Win: `%WINDOWS%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, Unix `/etc/hosts`) the line:

```
127.0.0.1 foo.bar.com
```

Now fire up your browser and connect to `https://foo.bar.com`. It will connect to your local server and post a SSL encrypted HTTP request. That request contains the hostname from the URL, not the real hostname.

I was oversimplyfying: The browser receives the SSL certificate from the server and compares the CN against the hostname it just called. If this matches, it will check if the certificate can be trusted (don't nail me down on the order, maybe it will check the trustlevel first).

Here is where you fail: The certificate provided by the server does not contain the CN localhost, and thus, the client will abort the connection. In your case, the client is the HttpSSLrequest.

To make the client believe all is well, you can do two things: 
- fake the hostname, and add the signing CA in the cacerts truststore.
- implement a hostname and certificate validator, that lets you through.

Regarding the tutorial, a self-signed certificate is used, you will have to convince the browser to accept it by overriding the warning on first access.

Comment: What is the configuration I should be looking for? I am not sure where the default trust store is set for JDK.

Comment: "It supports additional CNs and wildcard CNs.". what do u mean by wildcard CNs. Is localhost considered wildcard CN?  The request being send uses the localhost but the certificate that the server sends back does not have "localhost" in it.

Comment: A wildcard cert contains an asterisk and works for all subdomains of this domain: `*.foo.com` works for `bar.foo.com`, `baz.foo.com` etc. If you want to play with localhost, add it to the certificate. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help. It makes a lot of sense now. However I am reading this article and at one point it says you should be able to connect using https://localhost:8443/. Why should localhost be working here? The certificate doesn't have it right? https://te.systemautomation.com/docs/ssl-howto.html#Configuration

Comment: the client checks the hostname first. the server initially only provides the cert

Comment: I added some more information for you. I don't think localhost is working without warning on the client. If you add your certificate to the cacerts, it is trusted by default for java clients using that cacerts file, still the hostname must match or the access will fail. But you can add localhost to your self-signed certificate.